# SQLAlchemy Newest Item

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This should be simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's my table:

```
class UserEvent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_events'

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.user_id'),
                            primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    event_time = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    detect_time = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    new_state = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
```

And here's some example data:

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| user_id | event_time          | detect_time         | new_state |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|       1 | 2012-11-12 16:12:00 | 2013-01-31 20:55:31 |         1 |
|       1 | 2012-11-12 18:24:00 | 2013-01-31 20:55:33 |         0 |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
```

I want to find the newest (event_time) UserEvent for each user_id.

I've tried this:

```
for event, current in session.query(
        UserEvent, func.max(UserEvent.event_time)).group_by(
            UserEvent.user_id):
```

The query returns the correct "event" (2012-11-12 18:24:00). However, it is JOINED incorrect (or something) because "current" is True.

No matter how many rows are in the table, I always get back the most recent event_time and OLDEST new_state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using MySQL? That particular expression will generate query:

```
SELECT
    user_events.user_id,
    user_events.event_time,
    user_events.detect_time,
    user_events.new_state,
    max(user_events.event_time)
FROM
    user_events
GROUP BY
    user_events.user_id
```

which is invalid on most databases, but gives you a random row with MySQL. You may find out more about the behavior from http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5122798 (coincidentally, written by SQLAlchemy's author)

This expression would work:

```
for user_id, current in session.query(
    UserEvent.user_id, func.max(UserEvent.event_time)).group_by(
        UserEvent.user_id):
```

though it returns `user_id` instead of instances of `UserEvent`.

Something like this would probably give what you want:

```
t = session.query(
    UserEvent.user_id,
    func.max(UserEvent.event_time).label('max_time'),
).group_by(
    UserEvent.user_id,
).subquery().alias('t')

query = session.query(
    UserEvent,
).filter(and_(
    UserEvent.user_id == t.c.user_id,
    UserEvent.event_time == t.c.max_time,
))
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Interestingly, I did come across an example similar to this before I posted. I just assumed that it would be possible to do it in one query instead of two, although I suppose it could still be counted as one because "t" is a subquery. Anyways, thanks for the correct answer.

Comment: Glad it works :) As far as I know, the only way to avoid subquery in such situation is by using postgresql's `DISTINCT ON` syntax (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-DISTINCT), which is non-standard but really really convenient.